# Encoding issue when run bash script in background mode

Tags: php, python, linux, bash

I have a bash script to run python script with arguments and it's working perfectly in terminal but when I run it in background mode using php, it gives me encoding error. actually script doesn't have any errors.

The command in terminal is just `sudo bash total_report.sh`

Background mode in php script:  `shell_exec("sudo bash total_report.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &")` I know this is locale issue but please teach me how to solve this problem.

```
 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 59: ordinal not...
```

Comment: why add python tag here ? maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) can help you

Comment: That is the ® character, FWIW

Comment: Thanks @temmo. I've already checked but I don't want to change python code since it's working perfectly without any issues in terminal. but not working when I run it in  background via PHP

Comment: @AlexandrBiship since you are doing it with web you need to add instructions format ie utf8 acceptable by terminal

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by changing global locale of OS (Ubuntu in my case).

```
$ locale
```

[image]

In my case, `LC_ALL` was empty as default. run this command to set it up. (this is a temporary resolution. this value will be go away after OS restart)

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

You can also set it in `/etc/default/locale`. I actually don't know exact reason so any comments would help me and everybody.